# Unable to get system.display info in google chrome app

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am new to creating chrome apps and I am trying to create two windows, one on each display/monitor of my computer.  I am trying to get the displays' information by using the chrome.system.display.getInfo() but it is just returning undefined.

I've got system.display in permissions for my manifest.json and once I've create a window I open up the console and type in the following:

```
chrome.system.display.getInfo(function(displayInfo) { console.log(displayInfo); });
```

As I said before it just returns undefined.  From what I understand in the docs the argument should return back an array of objects that contains the info about the displays on the computer but it just returns undefined.

If I just type in chrome.system.display in the console I can see that it returns an object (which it didn't before I put in the permission in the manifest.json) so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more details it is hard to know what is going wrong. One thing I did notice was that there was no sample for using system.display, so I updated the existing system info sample to include this API.

I managed to do so without running into any troubles. You should download and try the sample [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/systemInfo) and use it as a starting point for your app.

If you're still having troubles please ask again here, with more details (i.e. more code).

Comment: Thanks Ben for updating that demo to include the display info.  The demo doesn't seem to run for me.  All it does is say "Loading..." on all items.  I'm currently running chrome 30.0.1599.101 on a mac. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have a version 30 on a Mac to try, but just verified the Display section works on 31 (beta) and 32 (canary). The other sections don't work on 31 because they need dev or canary version. Can you try running it in canary? Do you have a Display section at the top?

Comment: It appears that this feature is in 31 not 30.  Thanks for updating the sample though!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug, file it as one on http://crbug.com. Presuming that you have been trying it with a chrome version 30 or later (according to doc).

Answer (score 0):

Try  this

In your function

```
async getMemoryInfo() {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.system.cpu.getInfo(function(memory) {
            console.log( 'return memory', memory)
            resolve( memory );
        });
    }); }
```

When you call the function declare async and await for the promise

```
this.secret = await this.secureStorage.getMemoryInfo();
```

Answer (score 0):

@tomjnsn
In manifest `version 3` add the `system.display` to your `background.js` or `serviceWorker.js`

`permissions": ["tabs", "cookies", "storage", "system.display"]`